# Pass parameter to eventhandler from a closure

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I am trying to pass a parameter to my event handler. The binding takes place inside a loop, so I am taking care to add the parameter inside a closure. The paramater is not passed to the event handler though :(

The jsfiddle is [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/uo43wuoo/1/).

My simplified example tries to add a click event to every list item. On clicking the ordinal of the list item should be in the dialog box. The ordinal is derived from the loop.

The HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>last</li>
</ol>
```

The JS

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Generic function to bind event to handler
bindEvent = function(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
    }
};

sayOrdinal = function(ev, i) {
    // i is undefined :(
    alert(i);
    // this works though....
    // alert(ev.target.textContent);
}

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    bindEvent(listItems[i], 'click', function(i){sayOrdinal(i)});
}
```

The following code is corrected with help from the accepted answer.

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Generic function to bind event to handler
bindEvent = function(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
    }
};

sayOrdinal = function(i) {
    // Now it works :)
    alert(i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    bindEvent(listItems[i], 'click', (function(i) {
    return function(ev) {
        sayOrdinal(i);
        }
    }(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) that takes in `i` as a parameter. This makes it available to anything within the scope of that function. So use the IIFE to return a function that references `i`. Here, it ends up behaving like a closure because it is lexically bound to the scope of the enclosing IIFE.

```
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    bindEvent(listItems[i], 'click', (function(i) {
        return function(ev) {
            alert(i);
        }
    }(i)));
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eao135jj/1/)

Comment: I *do* want to invoke the predefined `sayOrdinal` function. Maybe not for the simplified example here, but my real life code needs it.

Comment: On a sidenote: your fiddle does not seem to be updated, nor do I get your code to work inside my fiddle.

Comment: @RoyPrins Fixed the link.

Comment: Here is me trying to make sense of this... A function is immediately called in the loop: it takes `i` as a paramater and returns (not invokes) another function which is passed to the event binder. The second function is only invoked when a click-event is detected. Because it was initiated(?)/returned earlier, it still knows about the correct value of `i` and can access it. In my case I use it to trigger yet another function. ~~ Hope that me making sense of this makes sense to other as well... edit: thx @Vivin Paliath

Comment: @RoyPrins Yup, I think you've understood it perfectly!